# Black texture appearing appearing on mesh

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures, mesh

I'm creating a voxel-world type game like minecraft in unity. When I render a chunk column full of blocks, so seem to render ok, but some are appearing as black:

[image: current scene]

You can see some of the blocks rendering normally on the bottom left of the chunk column. The problem is that black stuff that seems to cover that rest of the chunk column. I've tried lots of different light setting but I can't seem to get it right. I want the whole of the column to be illuminated like that bottom-left portion is. Can someone point me in the right direction.

Here are my light settings:

[image: light settings]

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by changing the ansio level of the texture atlas to 16 (max)